# Golang EmbeddedEntity to Datastore

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-datastore

How can I write an `EmbeddedEntity` to Datastore using the Golang `cloud.google.com` library?

I am working in a Company where we are migrating from GCP Java to Golang. Java Core requires that `EmbeddedEntity`s are written to Datastore, for Core to pick up and read certain things about users.

We are migrating to Golang, and require that the `EmbeddedEntity` be written from Golang. I've tried marshalling a `Struct` to `JSON`, and writing it straight. However, it still stays as type `String`. Changing Production code in the Java Core is not a viable option for us right now.

```
// VBalEmbeddedEntity is a Struct representation of a JSON entity
type VBalEmbeddedEntity struct {
    Properties Properties `json:"properties"`
}
type Properties struct {
    VT1_1 IntegerValue `json:"VT1_1"`
}
type IntegerValue struct {
    IntegerValue string `json:"integerValue"`
}

// Create EmbeddedEntity
bytes, err := json.Marshal(VBalEmbeddedEntity{
    Properties: Properties{
        VT1_1: IntegerValue{
            IntegerValue: strconv.Itoa(int(record.Amount)),
        },
    },
})
if err != nil {
    return 0, 0, err
}

// Generate Data using record
vbal := string(bytes)
f4Key := datastore.IncompleteKey("MyKind", nil)
f4E := F1_4{VBal: vbal}

// Datastore Put
d.DB.Put(ctx, f4Key, &f4E)
```

Comment: `IntegerValue.IntegerValue` is of type string. Consider changing it to int on `IntegerValue int...` and later on when its created: `IntegerValue: int(record.Amount))`

Comment: I will try it out, but the JSON datastore expects has the number in a string. I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: It's unclear why you are trying to marshal your VBalEmbeddedEntity into some format other than letting Datastore serialize the inner property like https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#hdr-Structured_Properties .  Perhaps an example of working serialized version would help understand the problem.

Comment: @JimMorrison Insane dude! That has perfectly solved my problem! I'll write up the answer now. No-one has asked about EmbeddedEntitys in Golang yet :) The JSON and Type in Datastore is the exact same as what GCP Java writes.

Answer (score 0):

To write an `EmbeddedEntity` using Golang to Datastore, you must do the following:

```
type EmbeddedEntity struct {
    VT1_1 int
}

type F1_4 struct {
    VBal EmbeddedEntity
}

func run() error {
    // Create EmbeddedEntity
    embeddedEntity := EmbeddedEntity{
        VT1_1: int(record.Amount),
    }

    // Generate Data containing EmbeddedEntity
    f4E := F1_4{VBal: embeddedEntity}

    // Put() to Datastore. VBal Field will be encoded as EmbeddedEntity type
    err := d.DB.Put(ctx, datastore.IncompleteKey("MyKind", nil), &f4E)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

Thanks to [@JimMorrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7644371/jim-morrison) for pointing me in the right direction! :)